# Count filtered by multiple rows of a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm stuck in a measure, I need to use DAX to calculate the count of students who passed only the 3 subjects at the same time. I've tried through VAR's and IF's but still haven't been able to get the intended result.
Below I leave an image with example data.

[image]

The right result will be 2, but with the options I tried it just gives me 4 or blank.

```
# Students =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Table[Student] ),
    Table[subjet] = "Math",
    Table[subjet] = "Writing",
    Table[subjet] = "Reading"
)
```

Thanks in advance for anyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```
# Students = 
VAR tbl = 
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Table',
            'Table'[Student ID],
            "Count", COUNTROWS('Table')
        ),
        [Count] = 3
    )
RETURN
    COUNTX(tbl, [Student ID])
```